# extracting data from db with jsp page

Tags: jsp

```
<%
RESOURCES res = new RESOURCES();
ResultSet rs = res.getAll();
while(rs.next()){

if( res.getSecId(rs.getInt("res_id")).equals(request.getParameter("sec")) ){
    out.println(res.getTitle(rs.getInt("res_id")));
}
}
%>
```

for this code, I have following errors.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:850)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5768)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5688)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5728)
.
.
.
```

Note: getSecId, getTitle and getAll are methods in RESOURCES java class and my db connection is in the other java class.

```
public String getSecId(int id) throws SQLException {
    String SQL = "select section_sec_id from resource where res_id = " + id;
    ResultSet res = db.getStmt().executeQuery(SQL);
    return  res.getString("section_sec_id");

}

 public String getTitle(int id) throws SQLException {
    String SQl = "select title from resource where res_id = " + id;
    ResultSet res = db.getStmt().executeQuery(SQl);
    res.next();
    return res.getString("title");
}
```

Comment: public ResultSet getAll() throws SQLException{

        String SQL = "select * from resource" ;
        return db.getStmt().executeQuery(SQL);
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
Before start of result set
```

This means that you're trying to get values from a ResultSet before you have called next() to positioning at the start of the result set. And indeed:

```
ResultSet res = db.getStmt().executeQuery(SQL);
return  res.getString("section_sec_id");
```

should be

```
ResultSet res = db.getStmt().executeQuery(SQL);
if (res.next()) {
    return res.getString("section_sec_id");
}
else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("I expect to have at least one row, but there is none");
}
```

That said, please, don't put Java code, and even less database access code in a JSP. This is not where it should be. JSP is a view technology. Its responsibility is to generate HTML, not to access a database.

Comment: that's exactly what i do! i just trying to execute query before resulset (ResultSet rs = res.getAll();) , then i try to get value from result set! ( I wrote getAll method in the comment below the post)

Comment: You're at least not doing it in getSecId(). And since you didn't post the complete stack trace, as you should ALWAYS do, I can't confirm that the problem comes from getAll(), getSecId() or another method.